# how to retrieve the urls using uipickerview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am developing one app using `UIPickerview` according to my project requirement. I want to download pdf from server.I am developing code but, errors occured. Please help me somebody.
I am new to programming.

`pdfviewcontroller.m`-

```
#define kStringURLViewControllerPDF @"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/UIViewController_Class.pdf"
#define kStringURLQLPreviewControllerPDF @"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/QLPreviewController_Class.pdf"

- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [listArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [listArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [listArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

    switch (component.row) {

        case 0:
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLViewControllerPDF];
            break;

        case 1:
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLQLPreviewControllerPDF];
            break;

        case 2:
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLUIDocumentInteractionControllerPDF];
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: You questions is missing, like the error you are getting.

Comment: `kStringURLUIDocumentInteractionControllerPDF` is not defined anywhere

Comment: you have to define this #define  kStringURLUIDocumentInteractionControllerPDF @"url"

Comment: What is the issue ? Your code looks working

Answer (score 0):

One error would be the fact that `kStringURLUIDocumentInteractionControllerPDF` is not defined above. 
We can help you better if you update the question with the error(s) that you are getting.